# Cannot require cloneDeep from lodash

Tags: lodash

`var cloneDeep = require('lodash/lang/cloneDeep');`

I was under the impression that you could require specific functions from lodash to increase performance but I just get an error saying `cannot find module lodash/lang/cloneDeep`. I looked at the lodash docs and I believe this is the correct path to the function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash removed category names from module paths since 4.0 ([Changelog](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#compatibility-warnings)). What you want is `require('lodash/cloneDeep')`

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat - ill accept after 5 mins when it lets me